# Formatting Cell Based on Value

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a Google Sheet and am trying to write a loop script. The idea is for it to read an entire column of repeating integers, 0-8, and put a bottom border under the cell with the highest integer which may not always be 8. The numbers will always be in numerical order, so once the cell below it contains an integer that is lower than the one above, the cell is bordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple for loop with an if loop inside of that. I tested it in a spreadsheet with data in the first (A) column, if you wanted it to run in a different column you would change the 1's in the if loop getRange(r, 1) to whichever number of column you wanted. I included the link to how to set borders also.

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592719/formatting-cell-based-on-value
//https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal


function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.ss.getActiveSheet();
//var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1";
var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
//var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lr+1); //Did not need for the current script
//var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();     //Did not need for the current script

 for (r=1; r<lr+1; r++){
   if (sheet.getRange(r,6).getValue() > sheet.getRange(r+1,6).getValue()){
     sheet.getRange(r,6).setBorder(false, false, true, false, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);

   }
 }
}
```

Here's the script run from a button with `getActiveSheet`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the script. My apologies as I am still new to Java. I tweaked the code to run in column 6 (F). An example of what I am working with is a column of numbers: 2 2 3 5 6 7 8 1 2 4 7 8 1 1 1 6 7 2 3 4 2 5 8 and and looking for the script to make it: 2 2 3 5 6 7 8| 1 2 4 7 8| 1 1 1 6 7| 2 3 4| 2 5 8|. When I ran this code, it just bordered the last cell in the column. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, I changed the column number, and then it wasn't working for me either so I changed the sheet variable to get the sheet by it's name rather than looking for the active sheet. In this example, I left it as "Sheet1" as that is the initial name, just have to change that text within the quotes to whatever that sheet name is.

Comment: OK, further test--if I started running the script then quickly clicked on the sheet I'm running it on, it works. It's not able to find the "active" sheet if you don't have it selected I guess. There are a couple ways to work around this while keeping the sheet being found by getActive, if you don't want to have to change the sheet name. One is to insert a drawing, make a textbok, then assign the script to the button by clicking the 3 dots in the top right of the textbox when you hover over it. The other would be to make a menu to run the script from, but that does get a little more complicated

Comment: So to sum up, you can use either the sheet = getActiveSheet() with it on a button, or use sheet=getSheetByName("sheet name") to run it from the project editor but have to change the "sheet name" if you want to use it in multiple spreadsheets.

Comment: Only way I got it to run was by calling out the individual sheet, which for my use case will work. Thank you for the help, much appreciated.